# Update vs. Request-Reply in Storm DRPC

Tags: java, python, real-time, nonblocking, apache-storm

I'm building a real-time API handling 2 types of calls:

1. Updates,
2. Computation requests.

Internally, the updates are broadcasted among workers. The workers keep working data structures (such as hash-tables) in their RAM, and modify the contents as the updates are coming.

When a computation request comes, exactly one idle worker handles it, using multiple threads, working with the local copy in RAM.

I'm wondering whether I could migrate my current implementation to Storm. As I understand it, Storm is pretty real-time and could help me a lot with scalability and fault-tolerance.

Currently, I'm using UWSGI/Python to handle the API requests, and Java workers to do the computation. I'm thinking of putting the Java workers into the Storm topology as bolts. However, I'm not quite sure about the spouts.

As I understand it, I could use DRPC to handle the computation requests, just by connecting to a DRPC server from python. It is clearly written in the docs that DRPC can handle the whole life-cycle of the request-reply paradigm. But what about updates?

My question is: Is it a good idea (or is it even possible?) to use DRCP to only submit updates in non-blocking manner, not waiting for replies (because there are no results)?

Answer (score 2):

For Non blocking, asynchronous Updates you should use a Job Server like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)

This will enable you to submit and need not to wait for any response. Gearman is used by Instagram to share photos to Facebook/Twitter whenever a user uploads a photo using Instagram app.

Comment: As I understand it, I should use an alternative solution as long as storm messaging does not fit to my use case, right?

Comment: Please don't use gearman, celery is much better. Instagram dumped gearman: http://www.quora.com/Celery-distributed-task-queue/Why-does-Instagram-use-gearman-instead-of-celery-for-their-task-queue

Comment: Being the only one to answer, I'm awarding the bounty to @shazin. My current implementation is based on ZeroMQ, but the problem was with starting worker instances. Anyway, I realized that Storm really does not fit well to my problem and I will continue using ZeroMQ (it supports both the broadcast and REQ/REP patterns), and use Marathon to manage workers. Eventually, in the future, I may switch to Kafka, yet the REQ/REP pattern in ZeroMQ is of great importance to my design.